# Dim DataTable = DataSet.Tables(TableName) -- copy or reference?

Tags: sql, vb.net, reference

Can't find a clear answer to this, but I need to be sure.  I've got the following code:

```
Dim daMyInfo As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from [" & TableName & "] (nolock)", objConn)
Dim dsMyInfo As New DataSet("MyInfo")
...
daMyInfo.FillSchema(dsMyInfo, SchemaType.Source, TableName)
daMyInfo.Fill(dsMyInfo, TableName)
Dim dtMyInfo As DataTable = dsMyInfo.Tables(TableName)
```

Later on in the code, I've got:

```
For Each NewRow As DataRow In dtMyInfoAdd.Rows
    dtMyInfo.ImportRow(NewRow)
Next
Dim objCommandBuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(daMyInfo)
daMyInfo.Update(dsMyInfo, TableName)
```

I'm assuming this means that `dtMyInfo` is actually just pointing at the same object as `dsMyInfo.Tables(TableName)`, but I'm not sure, and I'm more unsure because I haven't found this mentioned as a reference anywhere on MS sites.

Comment: If you're not sure, just count the number of rows in dsMyInfo.Tables after adding them in dtMyInfo

Comment: Use the **[Is](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx)** operator to compare references. `Dim result As Boolean = (table1 Is table2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DataTable is a reference type. You can see this in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.DataTable.aspx), that the syntax section shows it's a `Class`, rather than a `Structure`. This means that when you make the assignment, the value of the `dtMyInfo` variable will be a *reference* to the actual DataTable object in memory, and not the object itself. At this point, using the properties and methods of the variable is like using the properties and methods of the object in memory, and so adding rows to the variable adds those rows to the object in memory. As the `dsMyInfo.Tables(TableName)` expression refers to the *same object*, the new rows will be included here, as well.